# Worried about really overweight teen girl

Tags: teen

Beautiful girl 75 to 100 pounds over weight    She is getting terrible deep stretch marks that she thinks no one notices    It makes everyone extremely angry if anyone says anything.  Please send advice. She never goes out with friends or anything.  She is obviously terribly embarrassed and uncomfortable.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to the site.  For now, this is too broad for us to answer.  Can you clarify some details before we can really answer this question?  Start with what your relationship is - are you her friend, her parent, her sibling?  What have you tried so far?  What has she tried?  What are you hoping for here - advice for her, advice for yourself?  See [ask] and the [faq] for more information about how to ask good questions here.  Thanks!

Comment: Once a person is significantly overweight, it is *extremely* difficult for them to lose it. When they start dieting, the body fights to maintain their weight, and their metabolism slows. It may well be that the only practical option for her is weight loss surgery, which could *transform her life*. It shouldn't be done until she is mature enough to follow the post-surgery diet, though.

Comment: Where any medical reasons ruled out already? Has she seen a doctor?